# Create calculated column in one table using data from another table in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

Apologies for asking this, I see a few similar questions but unfortunately I don't really understand the answers given. I am fairly new to Spotfire.

I am trying to create a calculated column in one table based off of data from another table. The first table (which I am trying to add the new column to) is a monthly data census of all contracts the company has. Each contract has one row. Call it "monthly table". The second table is a complete transaction history for all contracts, so each contract can have hundreds of rows. Call it "total table".

I am not sure if I can link the data tables. I read in a few similar questions to insert columns from the table with data into the table where the new column will go, or to merge them beforehand, but the monthly table has about 13,000 rows compared to the total table's 550,000, so I am not sure how this would work.

I am trying to create a column to sum all the transaction amounts for each contract if the transaction type (also in the total table) is equal to a certain string. Like a "net transactions to date" column. I successfully created this column in the total table, but then each cell for a contract that meets the conditions had the transaction sum. I want it in the monthly table, where each contract just has one row, and it only displays the sum once. This is the code I have:

IF(
Concatenate([Contract_Number],"(transaction type string)",[Month],Year([Date]))
=[Type],
Sum([Amount]),
NULL)

It is currently in the total table. If possible I would like it in the monthly table, and for the [Number] and [Date] columns to refer to the monthly table, and [Type] and [Amount] to the total table.

Sorry if this is too much information or confusing! Also I know there is a problem with my summation (it is summing *all* transactions and only displaying in the correct rows, but it needs to only *sum* correct rows), but I think I can figure that one out, I just need help getting it in the right table.

I am currently working on transitioning a process/workbook from Excel to Spotfire.
If it would help I can provide the current formula used for this process in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more hours of tinkering, I figured it out! I thought I would explain what I did here in case anyone else encounters a similar conundrum.

TLDR; Made the desired column in the total table, and added the new column to the monthly table with a left single join on the contract number.

My month and date are tied to a document property which is a drop-down of unique date values in my monthly table. Within the total table, I used a similar code to what I've typed above, but instead of referencing the Date column directly, I referenced the document property, so it was pulling the date from the monthly table into the total table. I also switched from the form IF(condition, SUM()) to SUM(IF()) OVER (). This ultimately summed the correct values. For example, there might be five different types of transactions for each contract, but I only wanted the sum of two types. This resulted in the correct sum being displayed. The sum was displayed in every single cell corresponding to the correct contract number in the new column, so (in the same example) in all 5 contract #1 rows, the sum of the two correct types was displayed.

Then, I went to the data canvas for my monthly table, and added the new column. I chose a left single join, as each contract had only one row in the new table, so that the correct sum would only be displayed once.

End result code:

```
SUM(IF(Concatenate([Contract_Number],"type-string",[Month_ValDt],[Year_ValDt]) = 
    [Type], [Amount],0)) OVER ([Contract_Number])
```

Where [Month_ValDt] and [Year_ValDt] are new columns I made in the total table that display the month and ye
ar from the document property that is tied to the date in the monthly table.

Reasoning for the property is that we have a few years of data but I was told to make it dynamic so only one month of data is visible at a time, hence the drop-down.